# Uniform initialization with ternary operator return from function

Tags: c++, c++11, ternary-operator, uniform-initialization

I don't know if this is a compiler bug (gcc 4.8 on Arch Linux) or a problem with the standard,  but the code below fails to compile. Why is getFoo1 allowed but not getFoo2?

```
struct Foo {
    int _i;
    Foo(int i):_i(i) { }
};

Foo getFoo1(int i) {
    if(i == 3) {
        return { i + 2 };
    } else {
        return { i };
    }
}

Foo getFoo2(int i) {
    return i == 3 ? { i + 2 } : { i };
}

int main() {
    auto foo1 = getFoo1(3); //fine
    auto foo2 = getFoo2(3); //oops
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Braces *per se* do not form expressions (although all the *elements* of the initializer list are expressions). A *braced-init-list* is just a language construct that can be used for initialization in the contexts specified by § 8.5.4 of the C++11 Standard (including `return` statements).

If you want your `return` statement to compile and still make use of the ternary operator *and* of list initialization, you have to rewrite it this way:

```
return { i == 3 ? i + 2 : i };
```

Notice, however, that the above is not necessary. [As mentioned by David Rodriguez - dribeas in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16636709/uniform-initialization-with-ternary-operator-return-from-function/16636726?noredirect=1#comment23925436_16636726)), you could just give up using list initialization. This would work equally well:

```
return i == 3 ? i + 2 : i;
```

Comment: Alternatively, drop the `{}` altogether.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Right

Comment: I posted the code above to isolate the problem, but it was too simple I think. What about multiple parameters for the constructor or no parameters at all?

Comment: @ÁtilaNeves: I'm not sure I understand your question, but if the question you posted does not represent the problem you have, I would kindly ask you to accept this answer and post a new question with a more representative example

Comment: Fair enough. I might post another question. Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Per your suggestion I modified a line to be `std::variant<int, std::monostate> foo = (1)? std::monostate() : 1;` — but this don't compile, and can't say I am surprised.